# Multiprocessing: Pool and pickle Error -- Pickling Error: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I have two files:

x.py

```
class BF(object)
   def __init__():
   .
   .
   def add(self,z):
   .
   .
```

y.py

```
from y import BF
def FUNC((a,b,bf))
   .
   .
   bf.add(x)
   .
   .
   return bf

.
.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    for i in range(len(sl)):
         bf_set.append(BF())
    results = pool.map(FUNC,zip(sl, itertools.repeat(aa), bf_set))
```

I also tried to define BF inside FUNC, but sill I got:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

I've read some posts for related issues, but they have their pool.map() inside of the class, so the solutions cannot be applied to this problem (i guess).

Any idea?

Comment: One of the objects you're passing to pool.map likely contains a bound method. `<type 'instancemethod>` is type of `BF.add` and `BF().add`, for example. Bound methods are not picklable and therefore cannot be passed across multiprocessing boundaries on platforms without `fork` (Windows).

Comment: user4815162342 is right. you have something like `[].append` you pass on. this can also be an attribute in you BF class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to basically use what you have above, but turn it into working code.  There is no problem serializing, if you use `dill`.  I'm using a fork of `multiprocessing` called `pathos.multiprocessing`, which uses `dill` instead of `pickle`.

```
>>> def FUNC((a,b,bf)):
...   z = a+b
...   bf.add(z)
...   return bf
... 
>>> class BF(object):
...   def add(self, z):
...     self.z += z
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.z = 0
... 
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> pool = Pool()
>>> 
>>> f = BF()
>>> f.add(1)
>>> f.z
1
>>> 
>>> FUNC((0,1,f))
<__main__.BF object at 0x10d387f50>
>>> 
>>> FUNC((0,1,f)).z
2
>>> 
>>> sl = [BF() for i in range(10)]
>>> results = pool.map(FUNC, zip(range(len(sl)), range(len(sl)), sl))
>>> [bf.z for bf in results]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

This works, because `pathos` uses `dill`, which can serialize almost anything in python.

```
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(bf.add))
<bound method BF.add of <__main__.BF object at 0x10d383950>>
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(BF.add))
<unbound method BF.add>
```

Get `pathos` and `dill` at: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I got this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789149/python-multiprocessing-attributeerror-test-object-has-no-attribute-get-type