# Python Multiprocessing: AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'get_type'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, dill, pathos

**short short version:**

I am having trouble parallelizing code which uses instance methods.

**Longer version:**

This python code produces the error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gilzellner/dev/git/3.2.1-build/cloudify-system-tests/cosmo_tester/test_suites/stress_test_openstack/test_file.py", line 24, in test
self.pool.map(self.f, [self, url])
File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/3.2.1-build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.py", line 131, in map
return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/3.2.1-build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 251, in map
return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/3.2.1-build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 567, in get
raise self._value
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'get_type'
```

This is a simplified version of a real problem I have.

```
import urllib2
from time import sleep
from os import getpid
import unittest
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def f(self, x):
        print urllib2.urlopen(x).read()
        print getpid()
        return

    def g(self, y, z):
        print y
        print z
        return

    def test(self):
        url = "http://nba.com"
        self.pool = Pool(processes=1)
        for x in range(0, 3):
            self.pool.map(self.f, [self, url])
            self.pool.map(self.g, [self, url, 1])
        sleep(10)
```

I am using pathos.multiprocessing due to the recommendation here: 
[Multiprocessing: Pool and pickle Error -- Pickling Error: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396451/multiprocessing-pool-and-pickle-error-pickling-error-cant-pickle-type-in)

Before using pathos.multiprocessing, the error was:

```
"PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed"
```

Comment: Please paste the whole traceback - somehow the instance of `Test` is being passed instead of `url`

Comment: done, thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you need to use instance here? Can't you use functions?

Comment: this is a smaller version of something much bigger that I am working on. (https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-system-tests). I purposely made this as a scaled down version so I can put it here.

Comment: Are you on windows?  This `self._value` error often happens on windows when you don't use `pathos.helpers.freeze_support`, and run from `__main__`.  On non-windows systems, this error is much less common.

Comment: OSX, using virtualenv as to not interfere with system python

Comment: Ok, then you don't need `freeze_support`. This obtuse `self._value` error often comes from a pickling, coding, or other error that is thrown inside a multiprocessing call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using multiprocessing `map` method incorrectly.
According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map):

> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only
>   one iterable argument though).

Where standard `map`:

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the
>   results.

[Example usage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

What you're looking for is [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) method:

```
def test(self):
    url = "http://nba.com"
    self.pool = Pool(processes=1)
    for x in range(0, 3):
        self.pool.apply_async(self.f, args=(self, url))
        self.pool.apply_async(self.g, args=(self, url, 1))
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: pathos.multiprocessing doesn't have an "apply_async" method. but nevermind, I worked around that

Comment: You can also use `map` but you need to pass arguments in another way ;)

Comment: so now this example works, but I get a different problem in my real code, will open a new question.

Comment: I'm the author of `pathos`.  A `pool` in `pathos` has `apipe` instead of `apply_async`.  Or, if you want to use `apply_async`, then you can directly use the forked `multiprocessing` code in `pathos.helpers.mp.Pool`… which does have `apply_async`.   Similarly, `pathos` uses `amap` instead of `map_async`… however `pathos.helpers.mp.Pool` does have `map_async`.

Comment: I am now getting another error and I am not sure how to ask about this, since I cannot include the entire framework in one post. but essentially:     TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: Try to narrow down your code as much as you can and post another question. AFAIK you're `super` call is incorrect or insufficient.

Comment: I agree, that looks like a coding error with `super`, as opposed to a pickling issue, as @matino mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

The error indicates you are trying to read an attribute which is not defined for the object Test.

AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'get_type'"

In your class test, you haven't defined get_type method or any other attribute hence the error.

Comment: as you can see, I am not reading it in my code, this is mostly why I am asking a question

Comment: This is definitely not a solution